# When Inheriting from Screen Class Kivy attributes also show on the inheriting screen

Tags: python, kivy

So I want to access a variable from another Class. My problem is that if i do so the whole screen of the class which inherits to the other gets put on the GridLayout of the inheriting class. `FavouriteTrainingsContent` is inheriting from `SingleTrainingPlan`. Is there another way to inherit this variable? it is about the fav_plans list. Just write me if something is missing. Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

I tried to slim the reproducible example down but i couldn't really figure it out sorry... But anyways if you run the code like this and navigate from the nabber on the top left to favourite training plans you'll see what my problem is. You can also get rid of FavouriteTrainingsContent inheriting from SingleTrainingPlan to see how it should look like. Thank's for the help.

.py

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.image import Image

Window.size = (720, 1280)

import random
import sys
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
import os

from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer import MDNavigationDrawer

picture_number = 2


class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass


class GrdLayoutPlans(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        list_training_plans = os.listdir("training_programs")  # dir is your directory path
        number_files = len(list_training_plans)

        plan_index = 1

        for plan in range(1, number_files):
            btn = Button(background_normal="training_programs/Unknown-" + str(plan_index) + ".jpeg", size_hint=(.3, 1))

            lbl = Label(text="Training" + str(plan_index))

            self.add_widget(btn)
            self.add_widget(lbl)

            plan_index += 1


class TrainingPlans(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class ContentNavDrawer(BoxLayout):
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


class NavigationDrawer(Screen):
    pass


class CurrentStats(Screen):

    suggested_trainings = []
    trainings = []
    last_destroyed_item = None
    tr = []

  
    current_training_1 = None
    current_training_2 = None
    current_training_3 = None
    current_training_4 = None

    sgst_tr_1 = StringProperty()
    sgst_tr_2 = StringProperty()
    sgst_tr_3 = StringProperty()
    sgst_tr_4 = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CurrentStats, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.create_suggested_training_list(4)

    def create_suggested_training_list(self, r):

        for i in range(0, r):
            self.trainings.append(random.sample(range(7), r)[i])

        print(self.trainings)

        for i in self.trainings:

            if i == 0:
                self.suggested_trainings.append("Leg Weight Training")

            elif i == 1:
                self.suggested_trainings.append("Endurance Training")

            elif i == 2:
                self.suggested_trainings.append("Coordination Training")

            elif i == 3:
                self.suggested_trainings.append("Play Games")

            elif i == 4:
                self.suggested_trainings.append("ja")

            elif i == 5:
                self.suggested_trainings.append("Nei")

            elif i == 6:
                self.suggested_trainings.append("Gay")

        self.sgst_tr_1 = self.suggested_trainings[0]
        self.sgst_tr_2 = self.suggested_trainings[1]
        self.sgst_tr_3 = self.suggested_trainings[2]
        self.sgst_tr_4 = self.suggested_trainings[3]

        print(self.suggested_trainings)

    def destroy_first_suggested_training(self):
        self.current_training_1 = self.suggested_trainings[0]

        if self.current_training_1 == "Leg Weight Training":
            self.decr_chance_leg(1)

        elif self.current_training_1 == "Endurance Training":
            self.decr_chance_endurance(1)

        elif self.current_training_1 == "Coordination Training":
            self.decr_chance_coordination(1)

        elif self.current_training_1 == "Play Games":
            self.decr_chance_games(1)

        print(self.chance_ls_leg)

        del self.suggested_trainings[0]
        self.trainings = []
        self.create_suggested_training_list(1)
        print(self.suggested_trainings)

    def destroy_second_suggested_training(self):
        self.current_training_2 = self.suggested_trainings[1]

        if self.current_training_2 == "Leg Weight Training":
            self.decr_chance_leg(1)

        elif self.current_training_2 == "Endurance Training":
            self.decr_chance_endurance(1)

        elif self.current_training_2 == "Coordination Training":
            self.decr_chance_coordination(1)

        elif self.current_training_2 == "Play Games":
            self.decr_chance_games(1)

        del self.suggested_trainings[1]
        self.trainings = []
        self.create_suggested_training_list(1)
        print(self.suggested_trainings)
        print(self.trainings)

    def destroy_third_suggested_training(self):
        self.current_training_3 = self.suggested_trainings[2]

        if self.current_training_3 == "Leg Weight Training":
            self.decr_chance_leg(1)

        elif self.current_training_3 == "Endurance Training":
            self.decr_chance_endurance(1)

        elif self.current_training_3 == "Coordination Training":
            self.decr_chance_coordination(1)

        elif self.current_training_3 == "Play Games":
            self.decr_chance_games(1)

        del self.suggested_trainings[2]
        self.trainings = []
        self.create_suggested_training_list(1)
        print(self.suggested_trainings)

    def destroy_fourth_suggested_training(self):
        self.current_training_4 = self.suggested_trainings[3]

        if self.current_training_4 == "Leg Weight Training":
            self.decr_chance_leg(1)

        elif self.current_training_4 == "Endurance Training":
            self.decr_chance_endurance(1)

        elif self.current_training_4 == "Coordination Training":
            self.decr_chance_coordination(1)

        elif self.current_training_4 == "Play Games":
            self.decr_chance_games(1)

        del self.suggested_trainings[3]
        self.trainings = []
        self.create_suggested_training_list(1)
        print(self.suggested_trainings)


class SingleTrainingPlan(Screen):
    from changechances import add_chance_leg, add_chance_games, add_chance_endurance, add_chance_coordination

    path_i = StringProperty()
    fav_plans = []
    current_training = 1

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SingleTrainingPlan, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def show_training(self, current_training):
        list_training_plans = os.listdir("training_programs")  # dir is your directory path
        number_files = len(list_training_plans)
        print(number_files)

        training_path = [None]

        if current_training in self.fav_plans:
            self.ids.fav_btn.background_normal = "ButtonPictures/star-2.png"

        else:
            self.ids.fav_btn.background_normal = "ButtonPictures/star.png"

        for training in range(1, number_files):
            training_path.append("training_programs/Unknown-" + str(training) + ".jpeg")

        self.path_i = training_path[current_training]
        print(self.path_i)

        self.current_training = current_training

    def add_plan_to_favs(self):
        if self.ids.fav_btn.background_normal == "ButtonPictures/star.png":
            self.ids.fav_btn.background_normal = "ButtonPictures/star-2.png"
            self.fav_plans.append(self.current_training)
            print(self.fav_plans)
        else:
            self.ids.fav_btn.background_normal = "ButtonPictures/star.png"
            self.fav_plans.remove(self.current_training)
            print(self.fav_plans)


class FavouriteTrainings(Screen):
    pass


class FavouriteTrainingsContent(GridLayout, SingleTrainingPlan):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FavouriteTrainingsContent, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        for plan in self.fav_plans:

            lbl = Label(
                size_hint=(.7, 1),
                text="Training " + str(plan)
            )

            btn = Button(
                size_hint=(.3, 1),
                background_normal="training_programs/Unknown-" + str(plan) + ".jpeg"
            )

            self.add_widget(lbl)
            self.add_widget(btn)


class TrainingApp(MDApp):
    pass


TrainingApp().run()
```

.kv:

```
ScreenManager:
    MainWindow:
    TrainingPlans:
    SingleTrainingPlan:
    FavouriteTrainings:

<ContentNavDrawer>
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Home"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "mainwindow"
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Trainingplans"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "trainingplans"
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Favourites"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "favouritetrainings"
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Recent Trainings"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "trainingplans"
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Settings"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "trainingplans"
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")



<NavigationDrawer>

    MDToolbar:
        size_hint: 1, .1
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        title: "Navigation Drawer"
        elevation: 8
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer
        ContentNavDrawer:
            nav_drawer: nav_drawer

<MainWindow>
    name: "mainwindow"

    RelativeLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size

            Color:
                rgb: 0, 0, 0

            Line:
                width: 2
                points: 0, self.height*.96, self.width, self.height*.96

        CurrentStats:

        NavigationDrawer:

<TrainingPlans>
    name: "trainingplans"
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: (0, 0, 0)
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size

    ScrollView:
        size_hint_y: .85
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": 0}
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True

        GrdLayoutPlans:
            width: root.width

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1.006, .051
        pos_hint: {"x": -.003, "y": .85}

        TextInput:
            text: "Hello"
            background_color: (.22,.22,.22,1)

    NavigationDrawer:

<GrdLayoutPlans>
    size_hint_x: None
    size_hint_y: None
    cols: 2
    height: self.minimum_height
    row_default_height: 150
    row_force_default: True


<CurrentStats>
    name: "currentstats"

    RelativeLayout:
        size_hint: 1, .9
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": 0}

        canvas:

            Color:
                rgb: 1, 0, 0

            Rectangle:
                size: self.size

            Color:
                rgb: 0, 0, 0

            Line:
                width: 2
                points: self.width * 0.55, self.height - 2, self.width * 0.55, 0

            Line:
                width: 2
                points: 2, self.height * .9, self.width, self.height * .9

        FloatLayout:

            Label:
                text: "Your Progress this Week:"
                font_size: 24
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                text_size: self.size
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .52, "center_y": 1.43}
                halign: "left"


            Label:
                text: "Weight Training"
                font_size: 20
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                text_size: self.size
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .52, "center_y": 1.23}
                align: "center"

            Label:
                text: "Endurance Training"
                font_size: 20
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                text_size: self.size
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .52, "center_y": 1.03}
                halign: "left"

            Label:
                text: "Coordination"
                font_size: 20
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                text_size: self.size
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .52, "center_y": .83}
                halign: "left"

            Label:
                text: "Games"
                font_size: 20
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                text_size: self.size
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .52, "center_y": .63}
                halign: "left"



        Label:
            text: "Next Trainings"
            font_size: 20
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 1.08, "center_y": 1.43}
            color: (0, 0, 0)
            text_size: self.size
            halign: "left"

        Label:
            text: root.sgst_tr_1
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 1.08, "center_y": 1.23}
            color: (0, 0, 0)
            text_size: self.size
            halign: "left"

        Label:
            text: root.sgst_tr_2
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 1.08, "center_y": 1.03}
            color: (0, 0, 0)
            text_size: self.size
            halign: "left"

        Label:
            text: root.sgst_tr_3
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 1.08, "center_y": .83}
            color: (0, 0, 0)
            text_size: self.size
            halign: "left"

        Label:
            text: root.sgst_tr_4
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 1.08, "center_y": .63}
            color: (0, 0, 0)
            text_size: self.size
            halign: "left"


        RelativeLayout:
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 1, "center_y": 0}
            size_hint: .1, .8


            Button:
                text: "Delete"
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                size_hint: 1, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0, "center_y": 1.42}
                on_release: root.destroy_first_suggested_training()

            Button:
                text: "Delete"
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                size_hint: 1, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0, "center_y": 1.16}
                on_release: root.destroy_second_suggested_training()

            Button:
                text: "Delete"
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                size_hint: 1, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0, "center_y": .9}
                on_release: root.destroy_third_suggested_training()

            Button:
                text: "Delete"
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                size_hint: 1, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0, "center_y": .64}
                on_release: root.destroy_fourth_suggested_training()



            Button:
                text: "Show"
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                size_hint: 1, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0, "center_y": 1.33}
                on_release:
                    app.root.get_screen('singletrainingplan').show_training(1)
                    app.root.current = "singletrainingplan"

            Button:
                text: "Show"
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                size_hint: 1, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0, "center_y": 1.07}
                on_release:
                    app.root.get_screen('singletrainingplan').show_training(2)
                    app.root.current = "singletrainingplan"


            Button:
                text: "Show"
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                size_hint: 1, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0, "center_y": .81}
                on_release:
                    app.root.get_screen('singletrainingplan').show_training(3)
                    app.root.current = "singletrainingplan"


            Button:
                text: "Show"
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                size_hint: 1, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0, "center_y": .55}
                on_release:
                    app.root.get_screen('singletrainingplan').show_training(4)
                    app.root.current = "singletrainingplan"



<SingleTrainingPlan>
    name: "singletrainingplan"

    FloatLayout:
        size_hint_y: 1
        pos_hint: {"y": .3}
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size

        Image:
            source: root.path_i
            size: self.width, self.height
            allow_stretch: True

        NavigationDrawer:

    FloatLayout:
        size_hint_y: .1
        pos_hint: {"y": .1}

        Button:
            text: "back"
            size_hint: .1, .5
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .1, "center_y": .1}
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "mainwindow"

        Button:
            id: fav_btn
            size_hint: .2, 1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .1}
            on_release:
                root.add_plan_to_favs()

<FavouriteTrainingsContent>


<FavouriteTrainings>
    name: "favouritetrainings"

    ScrollView:
        size_hint_y: .85
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": 0}
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True

        FavouriteTrainingsContent:
            width: root.width
            cols: 2

    NavigationDrawer:
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: Your posted code seems to be over complicated to me. However did you try accessing the variable using method `get_screen` ?

Comment: @ApuCoder yeah i have tried it but it says: AttributeError: 'FavouriteTrainingsContent' object has no attribute 'manager'
And if i try to inherit from class it says:  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_screen'.

Comment: @ApuCoder and by the way i am pretty new to python and kivy so yeah i am doing a lot of things overcomplicated i think... But in general do you have like one suggestion for what i could do better like something that would make a big difference? thanks still for everything :)

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't need to (or should not) inherit from multiple uix widgets in kivy as that will result in completely unexpected behaviors. However, there are various ways to access (not by inheriting though) some variables of some classes from another class.

Here in your class `FavouriteTrainingsContent` if you want to access some var. of (`Screen`) class `SingleTrainingPlan`, you can just use its method `get_screen` without inheriting from it. But doing it directly in `__init__` there will be some issues like `AttributeError`. This happens because here you access kvlang via naming convention (as it turns out seeing you app subclass) and during the loading of this file there is no `root` (which is `None` by default) yet when it hits the class `FavouriteTrainingsContent`.

One way you can bypass this is by scheduling a method in future (i.e. when `root` is ready) as,

```py
class FavouriteTrainingsContent(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FavouriteTrainingsContent, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # Schedule a method responsible for widgets' creation.
        Clock.schedule_once(self.some_func)

    def some_func(self, dt):
        # Access the currently running app.
        app = MDApp.get_running_app()
        # Access the target screen and it's attr. and then store it in some var.
        fav_plans = app.root.get_screen('singletrainingplan').fav_plans

        for plan in fav_plans:
            lbl = Label(
                size_hint=(.7, 1),
                text="Training " + str(plan)
            )
            btn = Button(
                size_hint=(.3, 1),
                background_normal= "training_programs/Unknown-" + str(plan) + ".jpeg"
            )
            self.add_widget(lbl)
            self.add_widget(btn)
```